# Angular 13 - Data is accessible inside component, but does not show on the html page

Tags: node.js, angular

So, I am learning Angular right now, and tried doing a CRUD Application. Almost everything works, except when trying to get data using ID, I can access all the data in the `component.ts` file, but the same is not rendered into html file. Here is what I have tried :-

**edit-to.component.ts**

```
export class EditTodoComponent implements OnInit {

private tid: number = 0;

  public Todo:TodoModel= null ;
  public desc:string='';
  public title:string='';
  public id:number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(all_params =>{
      this.tid = parseInt(all_params.get('id'))
      //console.log( all_params.get('id'))
      //console.log( this.tid );
    });

    this.getTodoFromId(this.tid)


  }

   getTodoFromId(id){
    //console.log("id="+id)
     this.http.get<{data: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/todos/get_todo_from_id/'+id).subscribe((data) =>{
      console.log("response in angular= \n");
      this.Todo = data[0]
      

      console.log(this.Todo.todo_title) //-> This one works

}
editOnSubmit(form:NgForm){
  //something here
}
```

**edit-todo.component.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <form (ngSubmit)="editOnSubmit(todoForm)" #todoForm="ngForm">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo_id" [(ngModel)]="id" name="todo_id" value="1">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="todo_title" class="form-label">Title</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo_title" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" value="{{ Todo.todo_title}}">  //-> This one does not work.

      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="label" class="form-label">Description</label>
        <textarea  class="form-control" id="todo_description" [(ngModel)]="desc" name="desc" ></textarea>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit To Do</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Separating out,

from **edit-to.component.ts** :-

`console.log(this.Todo.todo_title)`  works

but from **edit-todo.component.html**

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo_title" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" value="{{ Todo.todo_title}}">`  does not work

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have a ngModel and a value configured on same input field

in this situation the ngModel have priority on value attribute

to fix it you can initialize title in `ngOnInit`

```
this.title = this.Todo.todo_title;
```

in your case you wait reply from http request so the initialization after hte http reply :

```
getTodoFromId(id){
     this.http.get<{data: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/todos/get_todo_from_id/'+id).subscribe((data) =>{
      console.log("response in angular= \n");
      this.Todo = data[0]
      this.title = this.Todo.todo_title;

      console.log(this.Todo.todo_title);

}
```

Comment: Let me try this. But, the method that you proposed, what if the number of input fields are more, like 20 or so ? is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: ngModel can be a property of an object. if you have a big structure i advice you to make a copy of this object in a model object and use it in your input. for sample a copy of Todo and assign `[(ngModel)] = todoCopy.todo_title`

Comment: I tried the method, but while I can access the data inside `getTodoFromId()`, I cannot access it insode `ngOnInit`. When I tried, `this.getTodoFromId(this.tid)
    console.log("Here"+this.Todo.todo_title)` inside `ngOnInit`, It says that todo_title is not a known property of Todo

Comment: yes you have an http.get in the method getTodoFromId so you have to set your data after the http reply

Comment: I did that. But, I cannot access the data in either ngOnInit or html page

Comment: while you don't have set this.Todo = data[0] after http reply data it will not be accessible

Answer (score 1):

Define a property of type BehaviorSubject.

```
isAvailableData = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

Then where you subscribe the data set it to true.

```
getTodoFromId(id){
//console.log("id="+id)
 this.http.get<{data: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/todos/get_todo_from_id/'+id).subscribe((data) =>{
  console.log("response in angular= \n");
  this.Todo = data[0];

  this.isAvailableData.next(true);

  console.log(this.Todo.todo_title) //-> This one works
```

}

after that in your HTML add ngIf to col-md-12 div:

```
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="(isAvailableData | async)">
<form (ngSubmit)="editOnSubmit(todoForm)" #todoForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo_id" [(ngModel)]="id" name="todo_id" value="1">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="todo_title" class="form-label">Title</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo_title" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" value="{{ Todo.todo_title}}">  //-> This one does not work.

  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="label" class="form-label">Description</label>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="todo_description" [(ngModel)]="desc" name="desc" ></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit To Do</button>
</form>
```

Also you made a mistake in your form the input should be like below:

And there is no need to define a property for id, title, ...
These are the properties of todo object

```
 <label for="todo_title" class="form-label">Title</label>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo_title" [(ngModel)]="Todo.todo_title" name="todo_title" #todo_title="ngModel">
```

Comment: I am trying it without Rxjs.

Comment: It is a best practice to use Rxjs. 
You can use boolean type too
 public isAvailableData: boolean;

Comment: And change ngIf to this:
*ngIf="isAvailable"